# rendering html from a controller in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-bind-html

Hopefully someone can point my in the right direction.

I am building a web app and part of it requires a user to click a button as fast as they can to obtain a score. The design dictates that I will need to show this score in double digits i.e 9 would be 09 so for styling I need to wrap span tags around each digit.

I have got everything working as required, I'm just having an issue with outputting the score that is wrapped in span tags as rendered html in my view.

I've put together a fiddle for the section that is causing me problems. Any advice, help, best practices etc is much appreciated.

**What I've tried:**

I've included a few of the things I've tried. Basically they involve using $sce and trying to ng-bind-html in the view. Attempt 3 seems the most logical to me but the $scope.count isn't being updated. I'm guessing I need to add a $watch or $apply function to keep it binded? but I'm not too sure how to implement it or even if this is good practice. Also, because I'm outputting html is it better practice to do this in a directive?

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/funkycamel/gvxpnvqp/4/

HTML

```
<section ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyController">

    <button ng-click="add(1)">add</button>

    <!-- First attempt -->
    <p class="first-attempt">{{ pad(count) }}</p>

    <!-- Second attempt -->
    <!-- in order for this attempt to work I have to call the pad2 function which
    returns trustedHtml -->
    {{ pad2(count) }}
    <p class="second-attempt" ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></p>

    <!-- Third attempt -->
    <p class="third-attempt" ng-bind-html="moreTrustedHtml"></p>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$sce', function ($scope, $sce) {

// Set initial count to 0
$scope.count = 0;

// function to add to $scope.count
$scope.add = function (amount) {
    $scope.count += amount;
};

// Attempt 1
// make sure number displays as a double digit if
// under 10. convert to string to add span tags
$scope.pad = function (number) {
    var input = (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number;
    var n = input.toString();
    var j = n.split('');
    var newText = '';
    var trustedHtml = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        newText += '<span>' + n[i] + '</span>';
    }

    return newText;
};


// Attempt 2 - trying to sanitise output
// same as above just returning trusted html
$scope.pad2 = function (number) {
    var input = (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number;
    var n = input.toString();
    var j = n.split('');
    var newText = '';
    var trustedHtml = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        newText += '<span>' + n[i] + '</span>';
    }

    // return sanitised text, hopefully
    $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(newText);
    return $scope.trustedHtml;
};

// Attempt 3
// Trying to sanitise the count variable
$scope.moreTrustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.pad($scope.count));

}]);
```

These currently output

```
<span>0</span><span>0</span>

<span>0</span><span>0</span>

00
00
```

Again any advice/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is going against the grain of angular.

Comment: Just use `ng-show` and bind the count to a `$scope` var

Comment: @CallumLinington: Care to elaborate?

Comment: @tymeJV: ng-show shows or hides an html element? The count is a scope variable and is holding the count. The issue I have is outputting the spans with that count

Comment: You've got controllers creating HTML code .... this isn't the angular way. Directives do stuff with DOM. Controllers just tie together services and view interactions.

Comment: @CallumLinington: I thought that was the case hence the last line of text under "what I've tried". Once I get it outputting what I want I'll move it to a directive. Thanks for the reply

Comment: why do you need extra span tag? just pad anything less than 10. You are grossly overcomplicating a very simple task in angular

Comment: @charlietfl: I need the span tags for styling. The client wants the counter to look similar to this http://watermarked.cutcaster.com/cutcaster-photo-100562848-number-clock-counter-black.jpg

Comment: So all numbers need to be shown, not just red ones? Still fairly easy using `ng-repeat`, split count string into array

Comment: @charlietfl: yeah sorry that image was just to show you. Basically there will never be more than 2 numbers as it's impossible to score that high. To start with it needs to show 00 not just 0 and each number will need to be styled individually (roughly like the image I linked). In my original fiddle I have it outputting how I want (attempt 3) I'm just a little unsure the best way to watch for the count variable as it's not being binded. My first Angular project and only 6 weeks in.

Comment: this should be pretty close to what you need http://jsfiddle.net/bey6tk4k/3/

Comment: @charlietfl: PERFECT! Really appreciate you taking the time to help. I'll mark the answer below as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far simpler solution:

HTML

```
<p>{{ count < 10 ? '0' + count : count}}</p>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;

    $scope.add = function (amount) {
        $scope.count += amount;
    };
}]);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bey6tk4k/)**</kbd>

If you prefer you can do the padding in the controller instead, just use another variable

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var count = 0;
    $scope.countText = '0';

    $scope.add = function (amount) {
        count += amount;
        $scope.countText = count < 10 ? '0' + count : count;
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I like the idea of doing the pad directly in the html it's just I need the spans for styling, unless you could suggest a better way?